# Can you cancel specific hits?

Tags: war-of-the-ring

**When you cancel a hit, can you distinguish between the the original cause of the hit?**

The shadow card Black Breath says that it triggers "if your Leader re-roll scores at least one hit".

In the scenario that the shadow player scores some number of hits on the Combat Roll and exactly one hit on the Leader Reroll, and the Free Peoples player has an effect that can negate a hit, **can the Free Peoples player choose to negate specifically the hit of the Leader Reroll** in order to prevent Black Breath from activating?  Or are hits no longer distinguishable from each other by the point in which they can be negated?

Comment: Can you give an example or two of an effect that negates a hit. I'm asking because particular wording of such an effect could be important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Board Games Geek](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/522726/heroic-death-vs-black-breath) cancelling a hit "simply means that one less casualty is inflicted". In the context of your question that would mean that you cannot prevent Black Breath from activation this way.